# How to extract particular tags from html in android using Jsoup?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have to extract (div id="content-body-14269002-17342313) tag from [this link](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/the-saeed-test/article17342313.ece) using jsoup. How will I do that? Can anyone provide a snippet of code of doing so?

Comment: Please let the community know what you have tried. It is highly frowned upon for simply asking code snippets of how to get stuff done, without you having put the effort. If you tried and are stuck at some place, the community can pitch in and solve your problems, but you have to make the initial effort.

Comment: Thank you,I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [selector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). The documentation even provides a code snippet:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...);

Element div = doc.select("#content-body-14269002-17342313").first();
```

Comment: Hi,I have an additional problem,the id keeps on changing everyday,how do I tackle that?